# how to do a factorial for loop and get final output

Tags: python

```
# Get N from the command line
import sys
N = int(sys.argv[1])

for N in range(1,4):
    N *= 4
print(N)
```

So, 4! is `4*3*2*1 = 24`.

My output is only 16 and it wants me to output 24

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things are wrong with your program.

1. It overwrites the input by using `N` as your loop variable.
2. The loop's `range` does not depend on the input.
3. The multiplied value is always `4` instead of being incremented from `1` to `N` in your loop.

Here is the correct way to implement the factorial:

```
# Get N from the command line
import sys
n = int(sys.argv[1])

result = 1

for i in range(1, n + 1):
    result *= i

print(result)
```

Or alternatively, use the `math` standard library.

```
import math

n = int(sys.argv[1])

result = math.factorial(n)

print(result)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks this one worked. Looks like I was doing the range incorrectly

Answer (score 1):

This finds factorial of number inputted from command line:

```
# Get N from the command line
import sys
N = int(sys.argv[1])

for i in range(1, N):
    N *= i
print(N)

# if input is 4, it outputs 24.
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend use math lib: https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html (cf math.factorial(x))

```
# Get N from the command line
from math import factorial
import sys

N = factorial(int(sys.argv[1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You inquire `N` from sys.argv and then overwrite it within your loop. That's one problem.

Next: range(a,b) will create integers from a to b-1 (assuming stepsize is 1). So `range(1,4)` will create `[1,2,3]`.

Your code does the following:
It changes N to 1*4, then to 2*4, then to 3*4 (which is 12, not 16).

If you want to code a factorial the hard way, you need a seperated iterator (usually indicated as `i`) and multiply all the way up to `N` times.